# c# Data table insert to excel with large record set is slow 4500 records over 6 minutes

Tags: c#, datatable, excel-interop

im returning an array of data from SQL to a data table. the reason for the data table is im re using the record set in multiple places.

When im using the data table to insert the data into excel using a for loop with around 4500 records is is extremely slow taking over 6 minutes. Im looking for some guidance on tweaking my code to make it faster.

I realize a lot of you will hate the comments I have however Im still learning and they are there to help me while I am writing this project

```
    void ExcelOutput()
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;
        object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        try
        {
            //Start Excel and get Application object.
            oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = false;

            //Get a new workbook. and set the sheets up
            oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            oSheet.Name = "Records";
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                oWB.Sheets.Add(After: oWB.Sheets[oWB.Sheets.Count]);
            }

            oWB.Sheets[2].Activate();
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            oSheet.Name = "Matters";
            oWB.Sheets[3].Activate();
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            oSheet.Name = "Notes";
            //Code to add another sheet if required
            oWB.Sheets.Add(After: oWB.Sheets[oWB.Sheets.Count]);
            oWB.Sheets[4].Activate();
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            oSheet.Name = "Optional FN LN Only Search";
            //Code to add another sheet if required
            //oWB.Sheets.Add(After: oWB.Sheets[oWB.Sheets.Count]);

            //reset back to required sheet
            oWB.Sheets[3].Activate();
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            //Add table headers going cell by cell.
            oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Data From";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Attatched to";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Key ID";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Subject";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Notes";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Contact Name";

            x = 2;
            y = 1;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtNotesConflict.Rows)
            {
                oSheet.Cells[x, 1] = dr["datafrom"];
                oSheet.Cells[x, 2] = dr["Attach_to"];
                oSheet.Cells[x, 3] = dr["Key_ID"];
                oSheet.Cells[x, 4] = dr["subject"];
                oSheet.Cells[x, 5] = dr["notes"];
                oSheet.Cells[x, 6] = dr["Contact_Name"];
                x = x + 1;
            }
```

Comment: Please add the rest of the method. Also try and split it into the integral parts and time them to find out, where exactly it's lagging. Then you can think of improvements.

Comment: Why do you use Interop instead of using for example ClosedXML library? Microsoft Office Interop has many drawbacks and Microsoft doesn’t recommend using Excel Automation (or any Office Interop) on the server: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

Comment: Thanks @LIDEN the process went from 6 minutes plus to about 6 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution about it. 4000 registers wrote in Excel in 6 minutes. I got reduce making next steps:

1. **Create a 2D array**

   object[,] arr = new object[list.Count, countColumnVisibles];
2. **Fill this object using reflection (in my case).**
3. **Calculate the Range where you will put the table.**

   Range c1 = worksheet.Range["B3"];
   c2 = worksheet.Cells["3" + list.Count - 1, countColumnVisibles + 1] as Range;
   range = worksheet.get_Range(c1, c2);
4. **Get the Range area using `get_value`:**

   Range range = worksheet.get_Range(c1, c2);
5. **Set Value:**

   range.Value = arr;

Important: 3, 4, and point 5 after to make the loop to fill the object array.
And work with 2D array not lists.